# Saving a signed XML in Google Chrome Browser via Visual basic (Back End)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to save locally an XML file via GOOGLE CHROME, I give the path and name, but unsuccessfully and it doesn't throw any exeption. It works with IE but not with google chrome:

I use the above method

```vb
Private Sub WriteSignedFile(ByVal content As String, ByVal pFileName As String)  
    Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.LoadXml(content)
    doc.Save(pFileName)
End Sub
```

Any help?

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but seriously, don't catch an exception and then rethrow it using `throw ex` as that will throw away the stack trace (unless throwing away the stack trace is explicitly what you want, but in that case, I'd strongly recommend a comment to indicate it).  If you're not going to do anything but rethrow, then don't bother at all.  If you want to do something like log and rethrow, then the right way to rethrow is just `Throw`. (For the benefit of future readers, my pending edit elides the empty try/catch as unrelated to the question.)

Comment: Where is this code?  Is 'content' a URI?